# How to copy cells via vba macro without getting subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

My macro to copy cells from one workbook to another is not working? Both workbooks are open and I am getting subscript out of range. Code below:

```
Sub Paste_OneCell()
Workbooks("DataWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Copy _
Workbooks("PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4")
End Sub
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing of `Workbooks(DataWorkbook.xlsx).Worksheets(Sheet1)` with `Workbooks("DataWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")` or with `Workbooks("DataWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets(1)`

And, of course, you must do the same with the other workbook/worksheet definition. In fact, your code should look like this:

```
Workbooks("DataWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Copy _
       Workbooks("PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4")
```

or

```
Workbooks("DataWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("C4").Copy _
    Workbooks("PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("K4")
```

Comment: Hi there, I left out the quotations when anonymising my example, but I still get subscript out of range. Any other solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: So, do you have two open workbooks, one of them named DataWorkbook.xlsx and the other named PasteWorkbook.xlsx? If yes, do each of the two workbooks have  a page named "Sheet1" and you want to copy and paste between those two sheets?? Or, both worksheets to be used are the first of each workbook?

Comment: Both have a sheet named "Sheet1"

Comment: @brutusbombocloth: Not really possible, I would say... So, let us try to debug. Please write a new sub with the next lines `Debug.Print Workbooks("DataWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Address`, followed by `Debug.Print Workbooks("PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4")`.  What do you see in Immediate Window (after pressing Ctrl + G)?

Comment: @brutusbombocloth: Does your new `Sub` stop on error? If Yes, on which code line? If this would be the first line, comment it and press `F5`. If the next line return something, your problem is in the first one. Or your workbook name would be "DataWorkbook.xlsm", instead of 'xlsx', or "Sheet1" is "Sheet 1" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Copy _
Destination:=Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets(1).Range("E5")
```

I got it from [MicroSoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)

But I guess there are many ways to do this.